# Updating IIS' default CRL (Certificate Revocation List)

Tags: certificate, iis-8.5, crl

I'm in the process of creating a (IIS 8.5) web server which will require client authentication. Client authentication will be carried out using client certificates which will be issued by a third party CA.

I want to be able to do the following:

1. Periodically check the third party's CRL.
2. Authenticate the client's certificate against the third party CA.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make sure that the root certificate of the third party CA is installed on your server. This ensures you can authenticate the client certs on the server.

A pointer to a certificate's CRL for is stored in the certificates itself, IIS does not have a default CRL. You need to make sure that your server has access to the `CRL Distribution Points` as specified in the client certificate.

Other than that, you don't have configure anything in regards to CRLs on the server.